# How to dynamically allocate arrays

Tags: arduino-nano, array, arduino-pro-micro, memory

Question given in the title. I'm trying to dynamically allocate the size of an array on runtime on an arduino pro micro. I've tried realloc, malloc and the c++ variant delete and new without success. This is my current test code:

```
int* test = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  if(test != 0){ //c++ delete and new attempt
    delete [] test;
  }
  test = new int[2];
  //test = (int*) realloc(test, 2 * sizeof(int)); //realloc attempt
  //test = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));          //malloc attempt
  test[0] = 1;
  test[1] = 2;
  int answer = test[0] + test[1];
  Serial.println(" " + answer);
  Serial.print(" " + test[0]);
  Serial.println(" " + test[1]);
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(100000000000);
}
```

All of my attempts result in either some garbage in the serial or in most cases:

```
test


test
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serial.println` doesn't work that way. Or more precisely `+` with string literal and an `int` does **not** create a concatenated string. Instead it treats the string literal as a `char*` and then does pointer arithmetic on it.

```
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(answer);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(test[0]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(test[1]);
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(100000000000);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
int* test = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  if(test != 0){ //c++ delete and new attempt
    delete [] test;
  }
  test = new int[2];
  //test = (int*) realloc(test, 2 * sizeof(int)); //realloc attempt
  //test = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));          //malloc attempt
  test[0] = 1;
  test[1] = 2;
  int answer = test[0] + test[1];
  Serial.println(answer);
  Serial.print(test[0]);
  Serial.println(test[1]);
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(100000000000);
}
```

In C/C++, you can't add/concatenate Strings and int.